# Cryptsetup failure after interrupted upgrade to 16.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, password, encryption, cryptsetup

My computer was interrupted while upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04. Afterward I rebooted and ran

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and rebooted again. Now, when prompted for my password on startup, nothing I enter works. I've checked caps lock and num lock and typed carefully, and have never mucked around with different keyboards. Indeed, navigating to GRUB and typing there, everything I type looks as expected.

Attempting to run from recovery mode leads to this exchange:

```
Please unlock disk sda5_crypt:
```

(I enter password)

```
Failed to setup dm-crypt key mapping for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/[some numbers]

Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher (check syslog for more info).

cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?
```

It's not clear to me how to fix this (apparent) issue with the kernel without being able to access a normal command line.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a solution to the problem as posed, but I ended up booting from an old kernel where sda5_crypt worked.

Comment: and did you uninstall/reinstall the newer kernel to see if the proper crypto module gets also installed ? that is the kernel-version you are running ? (have installed and try to run  ?) I made updates from 4.4 till 48 without and problems using a encrypted home/disk.

Answer (score 0):

When I run cryptsetup --help from Ubuntu 14.04LTS it shows the following at the end of the usual options:-

```
Default compiled-in key and passphrase parameters:
        Maximum keyfile size: 8192kB, Maximum interactive passphrase length 512 (characters)
Default PBKDF2 iteration time for LUKS: 1000 (ms)

Default compiled-in device cipher parameters:
        loop-AES: aes, Key 256 bits
        plain: aes-cbc-essiv:sha256, Key: 256 bits, Password hashing: ripemd160
        LUKS1: aes-xts-plain64, Key: 256 bits, LUKS header hashing: sha1, RNG: /dev/urandom
```

You may want to check if the aes module is loaded in your kernel, using `lsmod | grep aes`

http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=37276 had useful information regarding which modules are needed when the error you mention appears.

In my kernel, the module kernel/arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko seems to provide it.  It looks like it's a standard part of the kernel, so I'm guessing it's just not loaded by default.  The dependency tree in /proc/modules on my machine shows aes_x86_64 => aesni_intel and aesni_intel doesn't seem to have any dependencies, so it should be straightforward to load.

Hope that helps