# Not taking the crypt password after updating from 14.04 to 16.01

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I have updated my machine from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.10 LTS. After updating the OS, the machine is not accepting my crypt password, which I used to enter before Ubuntu booted.

Is there a way to bypass this password and log into the system, or will I have to format my machine?

Comment: "_before Ubuntu booted_" do you mean before you logged in, or before the login screen even came up?

Comment: I mean when ubuntu ask for the sda_crypt password....

Comment: what `sda_crypt` password. Please explain what you did before.

Comment: I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS before. It was having 2 passwords 1. cryptswap1  and 2. Password to login into the ubuntu.   System starts booting after entering the first password.  Everything was working fine.  The I update the ubuntu to 16.XX  with the command. Now the new system is not accepting the cryptswap1 password. Due to that, I am not able to login into the ubuntu.

Comment: In the above comment by cryptswap1, I mean disk sda5_crypt password...  After entering the password I am getting message: "cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options"

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/811054/cryptsetup-failure-after-interrupted-upgrade-to-16-04 I am facing the same problem. But solution is not given in the above url